# Spree set up errors: Devise Github Gem 'spree_auth_devise' & Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, devise, rubygems, spree

I'm new to Rails & wanted to try out Spree Commerce but have run into a few issues when trying to install Spree, I've been following the the  [Spree installation guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html) .

When I try to install Spree I get the below error:

```
C:\Users\Ross\Documents\eCommerce\Spree\test_spree_store>spree install
Would you like to install the default gateways? (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to install the default authentication system? (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to run the migrations? (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to load the seed data? (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to load the sample data? (yes/no) [yes] y
     gemfile  spree
     gemfile  spree_usa_epay
     gemfile  spree_skrill
     gemfile  spree_auth_devise
         run  bundle install from "."
←[31mYou passed :github as an option for gem 'spree_auth_devise', but it is invalid.←[0m

C:\Users\Ross\Documents\eCommerce\Spree\test_spree_store>
```

Below is my application Gem File:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
gem 'spree', '1.2.2'
gem 'spree_usa_epay'
gem 'spree_skrill'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :github => 'spree/spree_auth_devise', :branch => '1-2-stable'
```

I tried running `spree install` again without accepting the default authentication setting (N.B. I removed the last four lines of code from my gem file first).

```
C:\Users\Ross\Documents\eCommerce\Spree\spree_test>spree install
Would you like to install the default gateways? (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to install the default authentication system? (yes/no) [yes] n
What is the name of the class representing users within your application? [User] y
Would you like to run the migrations? (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to load the seed data? (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to load the sample data? (yes/no) [yes] y
     gemfile  spree
     gemfile  spree_usa_epay
     gemfile  spree_skrill
         run  bundle install from "."
      create  config/initializers/spree.rb
      create  config/spree.yml
      remove  public/index.html
      append  public/robots.txt
      create  app/assets/javascripts/store
      create  app/assets/javascripts/admin
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/store
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/admin
      create  app/assets/images/store
      create  app/assets/images/admin
      create  app/assets/javascripts/store/all.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/admin/all.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/store/all.css
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/admin/all.css
      create  app/overrides
      append  config/environment.rb
      append  db/seeds.rb
     copying  migrations
    creating  database
     running  migrations
     loading  seed data
        rake  db:seed
rake aborted!
wrong constant name y
C:/Users/Ross/Documents/eCommerce/Spree/spree_test/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:abort_if_pending_migrations => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
     loading  sample data
      insert  config/routes.rb
**************************************************
We added the following line to your application's config/routes.rb file:

    mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
**************************************************
Spree has been installed successfully. You're all ready to go!

Enjoy!
```

It seemed to work even though the the rake was aborted?  However, when I tried to run the server, it didn't work & I got the below errors:

```
C:\Users\Ross\Documents\eCommerce\Spree\spree_test>rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.9 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `const_defined?': wrong constant name y (NameError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spree_core-1.2.2/lib/spree/core.rb:53:in `user_class'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spree_promo-1.2.2/app/models/spree/promotion/rules/user.rb:7:in `<class:User>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spree_promo-1.2.2/app/models/spree/promotion/rules/user.rb:4:in `<module:Rules>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spree_promo-1.2.2/app/models/spree/promotion/rules/user.rb:3:in `<class:Promotion>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spree_promo-1.2.2/app/models/spree/promotion/rules/user.rb:2:in `<module:Spree>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spree_promo-1.2.2/app/models/spree/promotion/rules/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spree_promo-1.2.2/lib/spree/promo/engine.rb:45:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Users/Ross/Documents/eCommerce/Spree/spree_test/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Ross/Documents/eCommerce/Spree/spree_test/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from C:/Users/Ross/Documents/eCommerce/Spree/spree_test/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from C:/Users/Ross/Documents/eCommerce/Spree/spree_test/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

C:\Users\Ross\Documents\eCommerce\Spree\spree_test>
```

I don't know where to start with all these errors & am afraid of messing around with these files, also the rails server works fine in other rails applications(non spree) any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
ross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking as a Windows user with quite a bit of experience using Rails on Windows, I'll urge you to save yourself many headaches and set up an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS vm using VirtualBox or VMware.  Vagrant can make it a bit more automated for you.

That said, I'd make sure you meet the prereqs at the system level.

If you're not on Ruby 1.9.3-p327, upgrade to it.  That's not likely the problem but it contains some important security fixes.

Make sure rubygems is up-to-date by running `gem update --system`.

Make sure bundler and rake are at the latest: `gem update bundler` and `gem update rake`.  Do the spree gem as well while you're at it, if you didn't just install it today.

Start with a new project now that you are on the latest:

```
rails _3.2.9_ new spree_project [-d mysql if you're using mysql]
cd spree_project
spree install
```

Whenever you run any rake or rails commands in your project, you have to preface them with `bundle exec` as well, or else the wrong gems can get loaded and will cause you mysterious headaches.  So the proper command to run the test server will be `bundle exec rails s`.

See how that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for marking the answer.  You can also get help in the freenode irc group #spree.